# What is the reason behind this? (Not to be able to access class field from static method)

Tags: c#

that it is not possible to access class field from a static method inside the same class? I do not understand why designed like that.

```
using System;

namespace StaticMethodAccessInstanceField
{
class Program
{
    int m = 2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Display();
    }

    static void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
}
}
```

Note: Above code does not work. When I make field static or remove static from method header, it works.

Comment: Let's imagine that the class was called `Person` instead. And `m` was called `Age`. Then your `Display` method is meant to display `Age`. The problem is - **whose Age is it meant to display**?

Comment: thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because *instance* members are only accessible from an instance. Imagine if you created two instances of the `Program` class, which `m` should it chose?

You should specify the instance, so for example:

```
Program p = new Program();
Console.WriteLine(p.m);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't have an instance when you are inside the static method. So there is no way you could identify (let alone access) the variable you want.

Comment: Isn't class field visible to all methods of the same class?

Comment: @Lyrk Visible doesn´t mean *accessable*. The problem is: a static member has no instance which it refers to. However when calling an *instance*-member within a static one, how should anyone know, *which* instance you mean? There may be dozens of instanes of your classes around, so from which should the runtime take the value for member `m`?

Comment: I get it thank you.